# Why have some of my friends have gone missing from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, friends, friend-list

I was looking through my friends list and spotted this:

[image: Missing friends]

Some of my friends (well more like acquaintances, but you get the picture) are displayed in the list, but don't have a "Friends" button and the link on their name links back to *my* friends list.

I can think of the following explanations but none of them make complete sense:

1. They are people I've sent a friend request to that haven't responded yet. I'm not convinced by this as I'm sure that in at least one case *they* contacted me.
2. They no longer have a Facebook account. In this case I would expect them to be missing from the list completely.
3. They've blocked me. Again I'd expect them to be missing from the list. *(I'm not bothered if they have blocked me - as I said we're more of acquaintances).*

Is it one of these reasons or something else I've not thought of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I looked on my Manage Friend's list and found similar people. However, when I click on their names, a dialog box with the following message appears:

> This account has been deactivated. Only you can see {friend's name} on your friends list. You have the option to unfriend {friend's name}.

However, my friend's page looks different than yours, so there could be other reasons for this. Given what I'm seeing, it looks like 2 is the most likely candidate.

Comment: I'm now getting the message - odd that it didn't appear in the first place.

Comment: I have a couple 'friends' who keep their account deactivated, and will occasionally activate it for a few days.  I have no idea why.

Comment: I highly doubt this is the case. Because I received this message as well but before the link went to nothing before. There is a friend on Facebook that is experiencing lots of people ask them whether they have deactivated when they have not.

Comment: I have a few friends who get deactivated on a semi-regular basis, then come back the following week. I have no idea why. Either Facebook flags their accounts, or those friends have strange reasons for deactivating their accounts frequently.